# Secure cookies Asp.Net Core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies

In Controller  base class we get easily cookies value with httpcontext, but how to get cookies value in non-controller base in asp.net core ?`

> context.Response.Cookies.Append("name", "cookies");

`

Comment: Are you trying to get cookie information in a method you encapsulated?

Comment: sorry, this was an example for append cookies value i just ask how to get value of cookies in non-controller base class